# Change AS400 IP Address from Remote Session

Tags: ibm-midrange

We need to change the IP address of our as400 this weekend. I've found instructions to remove the routes associated with the interface, etc. However, our terminal that is physically connected to the AS400 is not currently working.

If I follow the instructions listed in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1017311 from a remote green screen session, will I lock myself out when I deactivate the TCP/IP address? Or will I be able to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will probably lose connection to the whole system if you dont do it carefully. And if so, how will you recover the system if you dont have a console?

You better setup a console to connect to the AS400 first.

I dont know what kind of server you have and how did you setup the network on this server, but normal setup is console and ethernet connection. COnsole can be ethernet or special port.

DO you have other ports available in the ethernet card? You can probably setup a new ip interface with the new IP Address and remove the old when everything is ready.

Comment: Thank you! We inherited this network, so I'm not sure what was originally setup. There are additional ethernet ports, so we'll probably try that.